# Updating lists inside tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

If I have a list inside a tuple, and then attempt to concatenate that list with another, I get an exception:

```
>>> a = ([1], [2])
>>> a[1] += [3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

This is expected: the concatenation is creating a new list, and tuples are immutable. However, despite the exception, the tuple is updated:

```
>>> print(a)
([1], [2, 3])
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: This is yet another case where using `.append` or `.extend` is preferable to using `+=`.

Answer (score 4):

That's because the concatenation (`+`) happens first, and then the assignment.

As the elements of the tuple here are `list`s which are *mutable*, the `a[1] + [3]` would succeed, but as the tuple itself is *immutable*, the assignment of the output of the concatenation to `a[1]` would fail (expectedly).

Comment: details [tuples-and-sequences](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

Comment: https://inventwithpython.com/blog/2018/02/05/python-tuples-are-immutable-except-when-theyre-mutable/